# ModuleNotFoundError when attempting to test working code

Tags: python

I have a test module which imports a class from trade_hub.py. For some reason, a ModuleNotFoundError is raised despite trade_hub.py running fine in isolation in the same virtualenv.

There are no other issues with any other modules. The only glaring difference between my ujson module and the others is in regards to  its install method; I used a .whl as opposed to pip.

The ujson module is imported by trade_hub.py.

My Package:

```
--bot
   --bot
      --trade_hub.py
   --tests
       --test_trade_hub.py
```

These execute without errors:

```
bot\bot>>> trade_hub.py
bot\bot>>> python -c "import ujson as json"
```

Here, in the same virtualenv, an error is raised:

```
bot\tests>>> test_trade_hub.py

import ujson as json
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

test_trade_hub.py:

```
from trade_hub import TradeHub
```

trade_hub.py:

```
import ujson as json

class TradeHub:
   """"""
```